# Hotmail refuses connections?

Tags: email

My server s sending out a lot of mail: account activation codes, notifications, pasword reset codes etc.

There is almost no problems with it. Users are receiving emails, including Hotmail users.

But from time to time in Exim logfile appears the following:

```
2013-02-16 10:14:19 1U6emh-0001W6-AY <= www-data@myserver U=www-data P=local S=1456 id=c48e11255262d6b44fa706ed3c7eab09@www.mywebsite
2013-02-16 10:14:19 1U6emh-0001W6-AY mx3.hotmail.com [65.54.188.126] Connection refused
2013-02-16 10:14:20 1U6emh-0001W6-AY => email@address R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp H=mx3.hotmail.com [65.55.92.136]
2013-02-16 10:14:20 1U6emh-0001W6-AY Complete
```

Can me explain somebody what does it mean? Why 65.54.188.126 refuses connection?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running from a dynamic IP or from a static IP that doesn't have a reverse DNS (PTR) record configured?

Larger mail houses like AOL and Yahoo will block such connections as they are often used by spammers.

Comment: I am running from a static IP that HAVE a reverse DNS (PTR) record configured + have SPF record. The problem is only with Hotmail and as I said 99,9% of emails Hotmail accepts without problems.